# How do I get all of the results from a hasMany() relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

For example, I have a Product, and I have a BaseProduct.

In the model for the Product, I've specified the following:

```
//In class Product
public function BaseProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("BaseProduct", "BaseProductId");
}
```

In the BaseProduct, I've specified the following relationship:

```
//In class BaseProduct
public function Products()
{
    return $this->hasMany("Product", "ProductId");
}
```

If I were to select a product, like so:

```
$Product::first()
```

I could get the BaseProduct by doing the following:

```
$Product::first()->BaseProduct()->get();
```

Instead of getting the array of the result from that, how would I get the `Model` of the BaseProduct, so I can get all of the children of BaseProduct, meaning all Products that have a foreign key relating to this BaseProduct.

I've tried `BaseProduct()->all();` instead, but it isn't a valid method.

---

Edit:

I've created the following chain of function calls - but it's awful.

```
return BaseProduct::find(Product::first()->BaseProduct()->getResults()['BaseProductId'])->Products()->getResults();
```

---

Final edit:

I had made a mistake in my `BaseProduct` model. In the `Products()` function, I had specified `return $this->hasMany("Product", "ProductId");` where `ProductId` should have been `BaseProductId`.

After I fixed that, I could successfully use:

```
Product::first()->BaseProduct->products;
```

As Sheikh Heera had explained.

Comment: Something like: $product->BaseProduct()->first()->products ?

Comment: That results in a `BadMethodCallException` unfortunately, since `BaseProduct()` returns a `BelongsTo` object, according to [the documentation](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Relations.BelongsTo.html)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To get the children of the `BaseProduct` you may try this:

```
$bp = BaseProduct::with('Products')->get();
```

Now, you have a collection of `BaseProduct` so, you may use something like this:

```
$bp->first()->products
```

Or get the second item from collection

```
$bp->get(1)->products
```

Also, you may run a loop like this (most probably in the view after pass it):

```
// From the controller
$bp = BaseProduct::with('Products')->get();
return View::make('view_name')->with('baseProduct', $bp);
```

In the `View`

```
@foreach($baseProduct->products as $product)
    {{ $product->field_name }}
@endforeach
```

**Update:** Yes, you may try this

```
$product = Product::first();
$baseProduct = $product->BaseProduct;

// Dump all children/products of this BaseProduct
dd($baseProduct->products->toArray());
```

You may chain like:

```
Product::first()->BaseProduct->products;
```

**Update:** Your table structure should look something like:

**Table:baseproduct**:

```
id(pk) | some_field | another_field
```

**Table:products**:

```
id(pk) | baseproduct_id(fk) | another_field
```

According to this table structure, relationship should be

```
// BaseProduct
public function Products()
{
    return $this->hasMany("Product");
}

// Product
public function Products()
{
    // second parameter/baseproduct_id is optional unless
    // you have used something else than baseproduct_id
    return $this->belongsTo("BaseProduct", "baseproduct_id");
}
```

Comment: Hmm - this is really close, thank you for answering.  Essentially what I'm trying to do is first get a Product, and then from that Product, get the BaseProduct, and then from that BaseProduct get all Products that have that BaseProduct as their BaseProduct.

Is it possible to use your method from first having the Product, instead of getting the BaseProduct first?

Comment: Unfortunately, that results in a `BadMethodCallException`.

I did perform what I wanted, and I've updated my question, but it's an awfully ugly mess of chained function calls.

Comment: You definitely made a mistake, anyways, the chain is derived from you and it's not awful `IMO`, it's smart.

Comment: @Zaemz, Also remember, `products` table should contain the `primary key` of `baseproduct` table or the connecting key of the `baseproduct` table. Do you have a `BaseProductId` field in your `BaseProductId` table ?

Comment: Yes, it does.  When I attempt your edit, `$baseProduct` becomes an object of type `BelongsTo`, and none of my functions available to the model are available to it.  Would you happen to have an idea why?  Thanks again, by the way.

Comment: Ah!  Your answer `return Product::first()->BaseProduct->Products;` did work!  I had made a mistake in my BaseProduct model.  In the `Products()` function, I had specified `return $this->hasMany("Product", "ProductId");` where `ProducId` should have been `BaseProductId`!

Comment: Even four years later after this was posted, this helped me immensely! I just wanted to say a huge shout out to @the-alpha for a GREAT answer!

Comment: Thanks @J.Robinson and wish you all the best :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = Product::find('id');
$baseProduct = $product->baseProduct()->getModel();
$baseProduct->products()->getModels();
```

Comment: remove the extra 's' on $baseProducts on the last line