# Laravel Eloquent model returns null for one to many relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am not sure what is going on here. I am getting returns of null despite having the info in the database.

**Stimuli Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Stimuli extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'stimuli';
  public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * Get the details associated with the stimulus
     */
    public function info()
    {
     return $this->hasMany('App\StimuliInfo', 'attribute', 'value');   
    }
}
```

**StimuliInfo Model**

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class StimuliInfo extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the stimuli associated with the detailss
     */
  protected $table = 'stimuli_info';
  public $timestamps = false;
    public function info()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Stimuli::class);
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App;

use Illuminate\Http\Requests;

class Labels extends Controller
{
  public function index()
  {

  }

  public function objects()
  {
    $stimulus = App\Stimuli::with('info')->get();
     foreach ($stimulus as $stim)
    {
      $stimuli[] = $stim->stimulus_id;
    }
   return $stimuli;

    shuffle($stimuli);

    return view('label/objects')->with(compact('stimuli'));

  }


}
```

Okay, so here is a test controller. For some reason, I am getting a null output for every data point. Which is odd as I can see in the DB that there is data there which is not null.

I am wondering whether I am doing something fishy in the model that is not right outputting this data.

Any help would be greatly appreciated -  I am at a loss for this process

Comment: Your field names are really attribute and value?

Comment: yea those are my field names in the database. Does that conflict with things?

Comment: while you define `return $this->hasMany('App\StimuliInfo', 'attribute', 'value');` in **Stimuli** model, i believe you should define the foreign key and primary key on **StimuliInfo** model too.. also, have you tried to `dd(StimuliInfo::with('info')->toSql())`. [if you wonder what toSql do](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql)

Comment: No, but it does seem strange that stimuli.value would equal stimuli_info.attribute

Comment: So I switched my foreign keys to the appropriate things on both models. Still null

Comment: If I return $stimulus then I get everything. Seems the problem is with the variable I am grabbing $stimulus->stimulus_id. I tried with $stimulus[1] and I only get the first. I also tried $stimulus[1]['value'] but nothing returns

Comment: You cannot access a `hasMany` relationship like this `$stimulus->stimulus_id`. See if [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21591715/4128530) will help.

Comment: Can you just do dd($stimulus) after query and show the output. @JPFoster

Comment: any solution to this issue?